# Pthread join or pthread exit of terminating mulithreaded c program?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I wanted to print 1 to 10 for 3 threads. My code is able to do that but after that the program gets stuck. I tried using pthread_exit in the end of function. Also, I tried to remove while (1) in main and using pthread join there. But still, I got the same result. How should I terminate the threads?

```
enter code here
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>



int done = 1;



//Thread function

void *foo()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
         printf("  \n @@@@@@@@@@@@@");
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

        if(done == 1)
        {
            done = 2;
            printf (" \n %d", i);
            pthread_cond_signal(&cond2);
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond1, &lock);
            printf (" \n Thread 1 woke up");
        }
        else if(done == 2)
        {
            printf (" \n %d", i);
            done = 3;
             pthread_cond_signal(&cond3);
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond2, &lock);
            printf (" \n Thread 2 woke up");
        }
        else
        {
            printf (" \n %d", i);
            done = 1;
             pthread_cond_signal(&cond1);
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond3, &lock);
            printf (" \n Thread 3 woke up");
        }
      
      
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);


        }
 

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return NULL;
}


int main(void)
{
  
    pthread_t tid1, tid2, tid3;

    pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, foo, NULL);
     pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, foo, NULL);
      pthread_create(&tid3, NULL, foo, NULL);

   
   while(1);
 printf ("\n $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please format your code consistently? Also, that's probably compiled with C or maybe C++, so add the according language tag. Further, this should be a [mcve], so if possible, reduce it from three to fewer additional threads. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Thank you!!! I'll keep that in mind!!

Comment: You can still [edit] your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How should I terminate the threads?

Either returning from the outermost call to the thread function or calling `pthread_exit()` terminates a thread.  Returning a value `p` from the outermost call is equivalent to calling `pthread_exit(p)`.

> the program gets stuck

Well of course it does when the program performs

> ```
>    while(1);
> ```

.

> Also, I tried to remove while (1) in main and using pthread join there. But still, I got the same result.

You *do* need to join the threads to ensure that they terminate before the overall program does.  This is the only appropriate way to achieve that.  But if your threads in fact do not terminate in the first place, then that's moot.

In your case, observe that each thread unconditionally performs a `pthread_cond_wait()` on every iteration of the loop, requiring it to be signaled before it resumes.  Normally, the preceding thread will signal it, but that does not happen after the last iteration of the loop.  You could address that by having each thread perform an appropriate additional call to `pthread_cond_signal()` after it exits the loop, or by ensuring that the threads do not wait in the last loop iteration.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Happy Learning!!!!!!!!!